# Angular $uibModal causing Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement $uibModal from [this site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

but as soon as I add $uibModal service to my controller I get Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModal%20%3C-%20dailymenuController
My angular code is below:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['djangular-confirm','djangular-alert','ui.bootstrap']).config(function($httpProvider,$interpolateProvider) {

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = '{$ csrf_value $}';
                $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
                $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
            });

            app.controller('dailymenuController', function($scope, $http, $location, $djconfirm, $djalert, $uibModal ) {

                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({

                });
});
```

I have added these two files:
  'ui-bootstrap-custom-1.3.3.js'
  'bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.3.3.js'

I am novice in angular and did little development using angular so far. I searched on google and SO and came to know that "ui.bootstrap" while creating module. But even that didn't resolve issue. Any help would be great.

Comment: You are injecting ui.bootstrap  and $uibModel correctly , maybe the issue is in the way of imports.
Can you provide the code where you are importing the dependencies?

Comment: What is the relation between `dailymenuController` and `App` modules?

Comment: can you present you html as well ?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error `[$injector:unpr]` states that Angular can't [resolve provider for the item](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) you're using - in your case need to inject `$uibModal` into your controller

```
app.controller('dailymenuController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal ) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
     //...
  });
}]);
```

Comment: I have already added that to my controller -> app.controller('dailymenuController', function($scope, $http, $location, $djconfirm, $djalert, $uibModal )

Comment: it depends on the build/structure of your project, but that may be the case that you need to specify the DI items in an extra array as I've proposed: ```app.controller(NAME, [ ARRAY_IN_QUOTES, function(ARRAY){ //code }])```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include both:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

After included Angular.